# How to change the line (______) under the table to dotted line under the heading in the table (---) in SAS?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to change the line (_____________) under the heading of the table to dotted line (---------) under the heading of the table in proc report step.
I tried using options formchar still its not working for me.
Can you please help me ? If data is required, i can send you in chat since the data is confidential

```
proc template;  
  %** Courier 9pt **;
   define style Styles.ods_9pt;
        parent=styles.rtf;
        replace fonts/
          'TitleFont2' = ("Courier New",9pt,Bold )         
          'TitleFont' = ("Courier New",9pt,Bold )          
          'FootnoteFont' = ("Courier New",9pt )       
          'StrongFont' = ("Courier New",9pt )         
          'EmphasisFont' = ("Courier New",9pt )
          'FixedEmphasisFont' = ("Courier New",9pt )
          'FixedStrongFont' = ("Courier New",9pt)
          'FixedHeadingFont' = ("Courier New",9pt, Bold)
          'BatchFixedFont' = ("Courier New",9pt,Bold )
          'FixedFont' = ("Courier New",9pt )
          'headingEmphasisFont' = ("Courier New",9pt,Bold )
          'headingFont' = ("Courier New",9pt,Bold )        
          'docFont' = ("Courier New",9pt );
         replace document from container    /   
          asis = on
          protectspecialchars=off;
        replace SystemFooter from TitlesAndFooters /
          asis = on
          protectspecialchars = on
          font= Fonts('FootnoteFont');         
         replace systemtitle from titlesandfooters/
          asis = on
          protectspecialchars=off;   
         replace body from document /   
            asis = on; 
        replace color_list
          "Colors used in the default style" /
          'link'= blue
          'bgH'= white
          'fg' = black
          'bg' = white;         
        replace Table from output /
          Background=_UNDEF_                                                
          cellpadding = 0pt   
          Rules=groups
          Frame=void;
        style Header from Header /
          Background=_undef_;
        style Rowheader from Rowheader /
          Background=_undef_;
        replace pageno from titlesandfooters/
          Foreground=white;
   end;
   
ods listing;  
options papersize='LETTER' orientation=landscape topmargin = '3.61cm' bottommargin = '3.61cm' 
        leftmargin = '2.54cm' rightmargin = '2.54cm' nodate nonumber missing=.;
ods rtf file="/home/u000000/sasuser.v94/Listings/listing_Demo.rtf" style=styles.ods_9pt nogtitle nogfootnote;
ods escapechar = '~';
options formchar='|_---|+|---+=|-/\<>*'
options validvarname=any;
options pageno=1;
proc report data=newb nowd headline headskip split='*';
    column num mypage TRT01A SITE BRTHDTC AGE SEX ETHNIC HEIGHTBL WEIGHTBL;
    define num/ noprint;
    *break after num/skip;
    define mypage /order noprint; 
    break after mypage / page; 
    define TRT01A/'Treatment' order descending center style(column)={width=1in};
    define SITE/'Site Id.*Unique Subject Id.' center style(column)={width=1in};
    define BRTHDTC/'Date of*Birth' center style(column)={width=1in};
    define AGE/'Age (YEARS)*[1]' center style(column)={width=1in};
    define SEX/'Sex' center style(column)={width=1in};
    define ETHNIC/'Ethnicity' center style(column)={width=1in};
    define HEIGHTBL/'Height*(cm)' center style(column)={width=1in};
    define WEIGHTBL/'Weight*(kg)'center style(column)={width=1in};
    *compute after TRT01A;
    *line '';
    *endcomp;
    title1 j=l height=10pt font="Courier New" "Protocol: XXX" ;
    title3 j=l height=10pt font="Courier New" "Population :XXX" j=r 'Page ^{​​​​​​​thispage}​​​​​​​ of ^{​​​​​​​lastpage}​​​​​​​';
    title4;
    title5 j=c height=10pt font="Courier New" "Listing";
    title6 j=c height=10pt font="Courier New" "Listing of Demographic Characteristics";
    title7;
    footnote1 j = l height=10pt font="Courier New" "20NOV2020 10:42";
 run;
ods rtf close;
ods listing;
```

@Reeza: can you help me with this?

Comment: FORMCHAR works **ONLY** for LISTING output (old school plain text). For HTML, RTF, PDF ... this option matter nothing. You are free to output to old plain text and you will have dotted lines.

Comment: if  i remove formachar also, i didnt work

Comment: You are able to use FORMCHAR options **ONLY** in ODS LISTING output (old plain text)! It does not make sense for PRD, RFT, HTML, so you could remove or leave it, it does not matter. I don't know how to make '– –' line in RTF or PDF output playing with a template. Look Richard's code below. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Way 1**

Add a `line` to the report.

```
ods rtf file='report.rtf' style=ods_9pt;

data class;
  set sashelp.class;
  page = 1;
run;

proc report data=class
  style(header) = [BorderBottomStyle=hidden]
;
  title;
  where name < 'H';
  columns page name age sex height weight;
  define page / order noprint;
  compute before page;
    line '-----------------------------------------------------------';
  endcomp;
run;

ods _all_ close;
```

[image]

**Way 2**

You can manipulate the report column headers by injecting destination specific characters.
You will also need to *hide* the header bottom border.

Example:

Change your style definition, replace

```
style Header from Header / Background=_undef_;
```

to

```
style Header from Header / Background=_undef_ borderbottomstyle=hidden;
```

and in the `Proc REPORT`, change the column headers to contain additional raw characters to be injected into the rtf table cell.

```
define TRT01A / 
  'Treatment*~{dest [RTF] ~{raw -------}}'
  order descending center style(column)={width=1in};
```

**Trick (LISTING)**

There is an `ODS LISTING` trick for `REPORT`:

- If a split line is two of the same *formchar* characters, they will be repeated across the column width.

```
* ODS listing only;
Proc REPORT ...;
...
    define TRT01A / 
      'Treatment*--`
      order descending center;
...
```

Comment: Thank you but i get dash line only under the treatment variable but i want a dash line under the headings continuously

Comment: @Reeza : can you check this?

Comment: Did you try a simple `LINE "-----"` in `COMPUTE` block, see edited answer

Comment: I am getting a line under each column but not as single line

Comment: LINE should do the trick, see updated working sample under Way 1

Comment: Thank you Richard...I got the required output :)